# How avoid docker0 interface starting?

Tags: docker

I run docker with my private `eth0m` interface as explained [here](https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework#local_physical)

I want to run docker without `docker0` and 172.... interface
how to disable `docker0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found.
First I configure my bridge0 via init scripts or NetworkManager,then
edit /etc/docker/daemon.json

```
{
  "bridge": "bridge0"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why would you remove `docker0` ?

> When Docker starts, it creates a virtual interface named `docker0` on the host machine.
>   [...]
>   But `docker0` is no ordinary interface. It is a virtual Ethernet bridge that automatically forwards packets between any other network interfaces that are attached to it. This lets containers communicate both with the host machine and with each other.

source:
https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/

Answer (score 0):

You need some bridge to run docker.
If you have another bridge for this, just delete default docker0.